# How to build regression model with partial dependent variables

Tags: regression, missing-data, model

Suppose we want to build a model to predict $y$ given $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$.
Sometimes, $x_1$ is not available, so I hope to predict $y$ given $x_2, ..., x_n$.
Sometimes, $x_2$ is not available, so I hope to predict $y$ given $x_1, x_3, ..., x_n$.

The naive way is to train combinatorial models given each possible combination of $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$, which is very costly.

What is the standard way to solve this problem?
If it is very hard to deal with partial dependent variables for regression models, what model would you recommend to deal with this situation?

Comment: It sounds like you want to make predictions with missing data. That is, you have a model to predict Y using x1, x2, ... , xn but you want to be able to predict Y even when you are missing some x_i. Is that correct?

Comment: Hi Ryan. Yes, in a sense it's missing value. Missing value imputation like median relies on interpolation. If I know in advance that a bunch of data doesn't have x1, can I do better? I guess the prediction of a model trained without x1 will be different to that of a full model with imputed x1. Is there any approach that design the model to predict with missing values? How can I incorporate the knowledge of expected missing values into my model? I guess in NLP, they mask tokens to build the model.

Comment: I think it also relates to the number of missing values. Missing value imputation seem to assume that only a small number of values are missing. If I know 1/3 if my data won't have x1, 1/2 won't have x2, 1/3 won't have x3... can I do better?